# Errors with PyZabbix host.create method

Tags: python, python-3.x, zabbix, zabbix-api

I'm getting this problem:

```
pyzabbix.ZabbixAPIException: ('Error -32602: Invalid params., Incorrect arguments passed to function.', -32602)
```

Here is my code:

```
add_host = zapi.host.create(
                host = host_sharepoint,
                status = 0,
                interfaces = [{
                    "type": 2,
                    "main": 1,
                    "useip": 1,
                    "ip": str(row["IP"]),
                    "dns": "",
                    "port": "161"
                }],
                groups = [{
                    "groupid": "27"
                }],
                templates = [{
                    "templateid": template_id
                }]
            )
```

Every variable that I am using is a string. I decided to look up my error and I was thinking that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138260/zabbix-api-3-4-unable-to-create-host-because-of-circular-requirement) was what I needed, but apparently I'm still getting erros, just different ones. Maybe It's an interface thing, I'm not sure. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-18128) is the explanation

[here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/70383) is an example

You need to change the code like this

```
add_host = zapi.host.create(
            host = host_sharepoint,
            status = 0,
            interfaces = [{
                "type": 2,
                "main": 1,
                "useip": 1,
                "ip": str(row["IP"]),
                "dns": "",
                "port": "161",
                "details": {
                    "version": 2,
                    "community": "public"
                }
            }],
            groups = [{
                "groupid": "27"
            }],
            templates = [{
                "templateid": template_id
            }]
        )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).